# How to remove the water domain box when rendering

Tags: rendering

I render the water, and the box will appear.
I want to remove the box.
If I hide the box, I will hide the water also.

Answer (score 2):

The 'box' you are referring to is called the domain and is required for liquid simulations, you cant remove it but you can turn off border collisions. You need to bake the simulation first.

To do this you have to **switch the cache type from *Replay* to *Modular*** and **check 'Is Resumable'** in the Cache settings of the Domain.

[image]
[image]

You can now go up to the settings and ***Bake Data***

[image]

Than bake the mesh out. Which can only be done once the data is baked first.

[image]

As said previously the domain is required for the simulation to take place. You cant remove it but you can turn off border collisions so the liquid doesn't collide with the boundaries of the domain. However the **liquid wont simulate or appear outside of the domain**, it will just dissolve/disappear.

Here I've provided an example of a liquid simulation with the both the data AND mesh being baked out. With these collision settings. Notice how the liquid collides with the walls.

[image]
[image]